# Add Running Apps to Picker in macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to fetch all running apps on macOS and add them to a Picker view, but I can't work out how to do it.

```
Picker(selection: $stopAppTerminate.onChange(StopAppTerminateChange), label: Text("Wait for App Termination ")) {
                var workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
                var applications = workspace.runningApplications
                var i: Int = 0

                ForEach(applications) { application in //, id: \.localizedName) { application in
                    Text(String(application)).tag(i + 1)
                }
            }
```

But the ForEach loop fails to compile with "No exact matches in call to initializer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Picker needs a binding of the right type and in the picker options tags of the same type.

As workspace.runningApplications is of Type `NSRunningApplication` you can define an optional State var of the same type. Then inside the picker you iterate through the applications with `ForEach` and the associated app value in `.tag()`.

```
    @State private var selectedApp: NSRunningApplication?
    
    var body: some View {
        var workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
        var applications = workspace.runningApplications
        
        Picker("App", selection: $selectedApp) {
            Text("No selection").tag(nil as NSRunningApplication?)
            ForEach(applications, id: \.bundleIdentifier) { app in
                HStack {
                    if let icon = app.icon {
                        Image(nsImage: icon)
                    }
                    Text(app.localizedName ?? "?")
                }
                .tag(app as NSRunningApplication?)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful. Please add instructive explanation.

Comment: agreed. Added explanation.

Comment: Thank you!  This is so close.  The picker is populated correctly, but the only issue is that i select an item from the list but when the picker closes it looks like no item is selected.  Opening the picker shows the item with a checkmark, but it doesn't show up as the selected item visually when the picker is closed

Comment: strange. when I run it the picker shows the selected item ... did you change something? Running Xcode 14.1 on macOS 13.0

Comment: ah, my bad.  I didn't include your "selection:" part as I already had one.  Using yours now works.

My only final issue now is that I want to have access via a timer to value selected, so I had the opening line set as

`Picker(selection: $stopAppTerminate.onChange(StopAppTerminateChange), label: Text("My label ")) {`

but your code breaks this.  Any thoughts how i could adapt your code?  Essentially, I need my timer to know which tag was selected

Comment: I don't exactly understand how your timer setup works, but you could add outside of the picker: `.onChange(of: selectedApp) { newValue in ...  (set timer for newValue) }`